# Get one image from each album using linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables `Album` and `Images`. Below is their structure.

**Album**

```
AlbumId      int      
AlbumName    nvarchar
```

**Images**

```
ImageId      int
ImageUrl     nvarchar
AlbumId      int [Foreign Key]
ImageDesc    nvarchar
```

I am trying to fetch one single image [Any image] from each album, to display it as cover photo for album, using `LINQ`. I am really not aware of fetching only one image based on each album as it needs some join operation [not sure though] and I have very basic knowledge in `LINQ` and `SQL Queries`. I am aware of how to fetch all the `images` from the table using `LINQ` which might be irrelavant here.

I have below model class for Images table to map with.

**ImageDateModel Class**

```
public class ImageDataModel
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImageDescription { get; set; }
    public string AlbumId { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

To retrieve all the images I just do

```
var images = (from img in db.tblImages select img).ToList();
```

Comment: can you show the code you use to retrieve all the images?

Comment: Would something like `images.GroupBy(i => i.AlbumId).Select(albumGroup => new { AlbumId = albumGroup.Key, Image = albumGroup.First() });` work?  Assuming images is your query to retrieve all images.

Comment: @Chandru - That will not select a single image.  It will return a collection of distinct images - which could very well be more than one.

Comment: have you try using where statement? where img.AlbumId == yourAlbumId

Comment: @EdT Is this Linq valid - `var images = db.tblImages.GroupBy(i => i.AlbumId).Select(album => new { albumId = album.Key, Image = album.FirstOrDefault() });` because I tried this but I am not getting any results..

Comment: Are you sure you are getting anything back from your initial query?  Also, how are you determining you don't have any results?  The query won't be run until you try to iterate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = images.GroupBy(i => i.AlbumId).Select(albumGroup => new { AlbumId = albumGroup.Key, Image = albumGroup.First() })
```

Note that you can chain this to your first query without the call to ToList and depending on the db provider it may translate it into the db's query language so you don't have to pull the entire list into memory before doing the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to group the images by album and then select the first item in each group as shown below:

```
class AlbumImage
{
    public string AlbumId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGetImages()
{
    var results = new List<AlbumImage>
    {
        new AlbumImage { AlbumId = "1", ImageUrl = "123.png" },
        new AlbumImage { AlbumId = "1", ImageUrl = "456.png" },
        new AlbumImage { AlbumId = "1", ImageUrl = "789.png" },
        new AlbumImage { AlbumId = "2", ImageUrl = "321.png" },
        new AlbumImage { AlbumId = "2", ImageUrl = "654.png" },
        new AlbumImage { AlbumId = "2", ImageUrl = "987.png" }
    };

    var imageResults = results.GroupBy(g => g.AlbumId).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
}
```

The above example will group the images by album, and then select the first image for each album.

Comment: It looks like @Ed T provided a similar solution in the comments.

Comment: Yea @JamesJohnson So I must wait and if he posts it as answer then must accept it.. Otherwise will mark this as answer.. Anyways.. Thanks for your time and +1 for your effort and time.. :)